# Restrict to specific dates in any year

Tags: xml, date, validation, xsd, xsd-validation

I am creating a schema that requires a date that corresponds to the end of a quarterly period (so YYYY-03-31, YYYY-06-30, YYYY-09-30, and YYYY-12-31).

```xml
<xs:element type="xs:date" name="FilingPeriod"/>
```

Is there a sensible way to accept these values in `date` format and restrict them to these specific but potentially infinite values (i.e., any year forever)? I imagine I could put some restrictions on a `string` field and validate that way, but that seems like a hack around using the proper `date` format.

Comment: Do you want the validation to be in XSD or in the backend ?

Comment: @LaurentSchoelens I would prefer it to be in XSD.

Comment: Same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28410780/validate-custom-date-and-time-in-xml-with-xsd) (with different need) and only solutions proposed are to change to xs:string :\

Comment: XSD 1.0 or 1.1? In 1.1 you might be able to use assertions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XSD 1.1 with assertion on simple type:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  
  <xs:element name="dates">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="date" type="end-of-quarter-date" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  
  <xs:simpleType name="end-of-quarter-date">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:date">
      <xs:assertion 
        test="(day-from-date($value) = 31 and month-from-date($value) = (3, 12))
              or
              (day-from-date($value) = 30 and month-from-date($value) = (6, 9))"/>
    </xs:restriction>    
  </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

[Online XSD fiddle in XML workbench](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xml-workbench/?code=%3Cxs%3Aschema%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%3E%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%3Cxs%3Aelement%20name%3D%22dates%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxs%3AcomplexType%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxs%3Asequence%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxs%3Aelement%20name%3D%22date%22%20type%3D%22end-of-quarter-date%22%20maxOccurs%3D%22unbounded%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxs%3Asequence%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxs%3AcomplexType%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxs%3Aelement%3E%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%3Cxs%3AsimpleType%20name%3D%22end-of-quarter-date%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxs%3Arestriction%20base%3D%22xs%3Adate%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxs%3Aassertion%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20test%3D%22%28day-from-date%28%24value%29%20%3D%2031%20and%20month-from-date%28%24value%29%20%3D%20%283%2C%2012%29%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20or%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28day-from-date%28%24value%29%20%3D%2030%20and%20month-from-date%28%24value%29%20%3D%20%286%2C%209%29%29%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxs%3Arestriction%3E%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxs%3AsimpleType%3E%0A%0A%3C%2Fxs%3Aschema%3E%0A&input=%3Cdates%3E%0A%20%20%3Cdate%3E2023-01-01%3C%2Fdate%3E%0A%20%20%3Cdate%3E2023-03-31%3C%2Fdate%3E%0A%3C%2Fdates%3E%0A&code-type=XSLT&input-type=XML).

Comment: Good answer, +1 from my side!

Answer (score 2):

I don't normally like using regular expressions for constraints on non-string types but in this case it's simple enough:

```
  <xs:simpleType name="end-of-quarter-date">
     <xs:restriction base="xs:date">
        <xs:pattern value="....-(03-31|06-30|09-30|12-31)"/>
     </xs:restriction>    
  </xs:simpleType>
```

and available in both XSD 1.0 and 1.1.